# Can I use explode() on the same $array multiple times?

Tags: php

As the title says, I am curious to know if I can use `explode()` on the same `$array` multiple times.

**I want the `$array` to be overwritten each time I call `explode()`.**

If I use it once it fills up the `$array`. But what if the `$array` is `not empty` ?

Will it override the previously saved elements ? Or will it add new elements on new, consecutive indexes ?

Is this a good practice or should I use different arrays for each `explode()`?

I've read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) and [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) but I couldn't find anything related to my question.

**This is the whole php page for reference:**

```
<?php

$defaultFilePath = "./defaults.txt";
// chmod($inputsFilePath,0777);
$defaultSettingsFile = fopen($defaultFilePath, "r");

$inputsFilePath = "./inputs.txt";
$currentSettingsFile = fopen($inputsFilePath, "r");
$arrayInputs = [];

if($defaultSettingsFile && $currentSettingsFile.filesize()<=0) {
    echo "Reading from $defaultFilePath";
    // Fill $arrayInputs
    $arrayInputs = explode(PHP_EOL, fread($defaultSettingsFile, filesize($defaultFilePath)));
    fclose($defaultSettingsFile);
    // Output $arrayInputs
    var_dump($arrayInputs);
    $URL = $arrayInputs[0];
    $Timer = $arrayInputs[1];
    $Brightness = $arrayInputs[2];
}elseif($currentSettingsFile) {
    echo "Reading from $inputsFilePath";
    // Fill $arrayInputs
    $arrayInputs = explode(PHP_EOL, fread($currentSettingsFile, filesize($inputsFilePath)));
    $closeFlag = fclose($currentSettingsFile);
    // Output $arrayInputs
    var_dump($arrayInputs);
    $URL = $arrayInputs[0];
    $Timer = $arrayInputs[1];
    $Brightness = $arrayInputs[2];
}

//If Default Settings Button was pressed:
if(isset( $_POST['default_settings'])) {
    $defaultSettingsFile = fopen($defaultFilePath, "r");
    if($defaultSettingsFile) {
        echo "Reading from $defaultFilePath";
        // Fill $arrayInputs
        $arrayInputs = explode(PHP_EOL, fread($defaultSettingsFile, filesize($defaultFilePath)));
        fclose($defaultSettingsFile);
        // Output $arrayInputs
        var_dump($arrayInputs);
        $URL = $arrayInputs[0];
        $Timer = $arrayInputs[1];
        $Brightness = $arrayInputs[2];
    } else {
        echo "\nCouldn't change to Default Settings - defaults.txt couldn't be open !\n";
      }
}


// retrieve the form data by using the element's name attributes value as key
// If you press on "Save Values" button
if(isset( $_POST['save_values'])) {

    if(!empty($_POST['getURL'])) {
        $URL = $_POST['getURL'];
        $arrayInputs[0] = $URL;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['getTimer'])) {
        $Timer = $_POST['getTimer'];
        $arrayInputs[1] = $Timer;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['getBrightness'])) {
        $Brightness = $_POST['getBrightness'];
        $arrayInputs[2] = $Brightness;
    }
}

if(!$closeFlag) fclose($currentSettingsFile);

$currentSettingsFile = fopen($inputsFilePath, "c");
if($currentSettingsFile) {
    echo "Writing in $inputsFilePath";
    echo fwrite($currentSettingsFile,$arrayInputs[0].PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($currentSettingsFile,$arrayInputs[1].PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($currentSettingsFile,$arrayInputs[2].PHP_EOL);
    fclose($currentSettingsFile);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not about the behaviour of `explode()`, it only returns an array. It is your assignment that is overwriting the variable each time. If you want to append the results of consecutive explodes you need to use [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). The [Union operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) suggested in the comments will not work for the results of `explode()`, because it is not an associative array.

```
$str = '1-2-3';
$arr = explode('-', $str);
$str = '4-5-6';
$arr = array_merge($arr, explode('-', $str));
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "6"
}
```

Comment: I actually want the `$array` to be overwritten. Thank you for confirming it's behavior and for giving me an option in case I want to append to an `$array`.